Zola inheritance with papermod
Zola theme papermod is nicely laid out so that main templates include smaller pieces from directory partials. For example, index.html includes partials/head.html.
In partials/head.html, there are blocks. For example,
{% block head_favicons %}
{% endblock %}

I want to use the theme as is, and therefore, I have to somehow inherit partials/head.html and modify this block.
The standard way making overwriting index.html like:
{% extends "papermod/templates/index.html" %}
{% block head_favicons %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg">
{% endblock head_favicons %}

Does not work. I guess the blocks are not extended if they come from the included source file.
Another way is overwriting file partials/head.html and using inheritance there:
{% extends "papermod/templates/partials/head.html" %}
{% block head_favicons %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg">
{% endblock head_favicons %}

Gives an error message: "Inheritance in included templates is currently not supported".
I can overwrite the whole partials/head.html, but then I am essentially copying the whole theme and making random changes to the original. The file is 100 lines of code, and I want to change three. And this applies to all 13 partials.
So, is there a way to nicely overwrite blocks inside papermod partials?
